# Setting CTreeCtrl item's checkbox to partial state

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, mfc

First I add TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES to the CTreeCtrl's extended styles:

```
TreeView_SetExtendedStyle(tree->GetSafeHwnd(), TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES, TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES);
```

Now how do I actually set any item to this state? There doesn't appear to be any documentation about that. I guessed that since checking and unchecking works by changing the item's state image to 1 or 2, I can try my luck with 3:

```
tree->SetItemState(tree->GetFirstVisibleItem(), INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(3), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
```

Of course that would have been too easy, it just made the image disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `tree->SetCheck()` instead of `tree->SetItemState()`, Try setting check state to 2.

Comment: The parameter to SetCheck is BOOL, which means it will be treated as TRUE either way.